# Scheduling a thread with QTtimer?

Tags: multithreading, qt, time, thread-safety

I am working with an extended famous Producer-Consumer problem with threads (for a homework). I have a shared queue as "my buffer" and the producer needs to produce an "element" every second.

I am using (my first time...) QT and I want a timer so that every second the producer will generate the element.

I dont understand QTimer library... Can someone give me an advise of what library/functions I have to use for the timer? Is just that QTimer seems to be for GUI... If Qtimer is what I have to use, then how?

Maybe this is a dumb question, but this little thing is taking me too much time... And I dont find an aswer.

Comment: If no event loop in your producer, why not just use a Sleep() loop?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure a QEventLoop is running in each thread that needs to do work (with QObject's).

You will have a main event loop already (the "GUI Thread") that runs the `QApplication.exec()`.

Then you create another thread (to do parallel work) you have QEventLoop in that thread that runs.  You would usualy make sure the QObject's (that do work in this extra thread) have this extra thread as their "affinity thread".  If you create and instate the QObject from within the extra thread the new QObject's affinity thread will be the current thread.

Other than this you pass signal/slot between threads using QueuedConnection.

I'm sure there are plenty of example QTimer code blog entries around if you search.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use Qtimer to emit a signal every second.Then connect a slot to that signal where you can kick start a thread but you have to manage shared resources("my buffer") across thread.

`QTimer timer=new QTimer();
 connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(On_Timeout));

 timer->start(1000);`

Where On_Timeout is executed every second.

Here are some basic tutorial on Qtimer.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHc7siV2Ads